# Sort a list of lists alphabetically by the first two items in the list in Python

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have this inputs in python:

```
4
m.hosSein.python
f.miNa.C
m.aHMad.C++
f.Sara.java
```

(f:female, m:male, names, language program)

and I want to sort and standardize these form to below form:

f Mina C
f Sara java
m Ahmad C++
m Hossein python

I write this program:

```
input1=int(input())

results = []
for k in range(input1):
    input2 = input().split(".")
    results.append(input2)

results.sort(key=lambda x:(x[0::]), reverse=False)

for i in results:
    i[1]=str(i[1])
    i[1]=i[1].title()
    print(i[0],str(i[1]), i[2])
```

but this program gives me:

f Sara java
f Mina C
m Ahmad C++
m Hossein python

that, it output is wrong, because I want give "Mina" befor "Sara" in the name,

please help me.

```
    input1=int(input())

    results = []
    for k in range(input1):
      input2 = input().split(".")
      results.append(input2)
 
    results.sort(key=lambda x:(x[0::]), reverse=False)

    for i in results:
      i[1]=str(i[1])
      i[1]=i[1].title()
      print(i[0],str(i[1]), i[2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Altering your `sort` operation as follows produces the result you want:

```
results.sort(key=lambda x:(x[0], x[1]), reverse=False)
```